# Accessing a Lua table within a table from C++ side

Tags: c++, lua

I'm trying to transfer a table where there may be nested tables from the lua and write to a **.ini** file. But I just can not how I need to go on the stack to get data from nested tables. This code does not work as it should. Function **setData** work not correctly. What could be the problem?

**C++ code**

```
int sasl::LuaUtilities::luaWriteIni(LuaState inOutState)
{   
    string path;
    boost::property_tree::ptree iniTree;
    LUA_CHECK_NARG_EQ(inOutState, 2);
    LUA_GET_PARAM(inOutState, 1, path);
    int nargs = lua_gettop(inOutState);
    for (int i = 1; i <= nargs; i++) {
        if (lua_istable(inOutState, nargs)) {
            setData(inOutState, nargs, iniTree);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void sasl::LuaUtilities::setData(LuaState inOutState, int index, boost::property_tree::ptree & inIniTree)
{
    // Push an initial nil to init lua_next
    lua_pushnil(inOutState);
    // Parse the table at index
    while (lua_next(inOutState, index))
    {
        if (lua_istable(inOutState, index))
        {
            setData(inOutState, index, inIniTree);
        }
        else
        {
            string key = lua_tostring(inOutState, -2);
            string value = lua_tostring(inOutState, -1);
        }
        // Pop value, keep key
        lua_pop(inOutState, 1);
    }
    return;
}
```

**Lua code**

```
t = {}
local fileName = findResourceFile("test.ini")
t = readINI(fileName)
writeINI(fileName, t) --this not work in c++ side
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems. `lua_istable(inOutState, index)` is wrong, because `index` is not the value of the key retrieved by `next`. That index is always the table you're iterating over. So you'll infinitely recurse over the same table when you call `setData` with that index.

In fact, passing `index` to `setData` itself is almost certainly wrong. Or at least, it's probably not right. You want to use relative indices here, but calling `next` pushes an extra value onto the stack.

What you probably want to do is have `setData` assume that the table to iterate over is at index -1 (ie: the top of the stack). That way, you're just calling `lua_next(state, -2)` (this is -2 because the key to get the next one for is at the top). And when you recursively call `setData` for a table value, you don't need to provide an index, because the table value is already at the top of the stack.

The second problem is that you never write the key/value pairs. You also never check to see if the value is something which can be converted to a string. It could be a Lua userdata.